# Callback/ hook which when document in elasticsearch is updated

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch

Just as the title described, I want to define a callback/hook that can be invoked when a document is updated.

What i want is to get the document data before and after updated.I did some investigation and i think maybe i can do it through the elastic plugin, would IndexingOperationListener be my answer?If it would be, can anybody tell me where to find the implementation of update so I can determine which callback method should I override

```
/**
 * Called before the indexing occurs.
 */
public Engine.Create preCreate(Engine.Create create)

//...
```

Comment: Why do you need this? You need to every document, or for specific documents?

Comment: That would be cool - similar to rethinkdb feature. Maybe you are looking for Watcher plugin?